# Checking existing URL

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to make this working code to check if `URL` exists (coded Visual C++):

```
void urlexists() 
{
    try 
    {
        LPCWSTR pfile(NULL);
        HRESULT hRez = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, _T("http://google.com"), (pfile), 0, NULL);
        if (hRez != 0)
            return;
    }
    catch (...) 
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

and make it portable for *linux* distros. What should I do? I didn't found nothing on Internet

Comment: What doesn't work? What do you mean by "URL exists"? You will probably need to learn how HTTP works before proceeding any further.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the process goes, if you make a GET request to the URL, you will get a 200/OK code back if the resource exists. You will receive a 404 if it does not. Your file will be in the body of the request if the request succeeds. You then copy the request body to the file on disk.

There isn't a good way to make this portable without writing a libcurl, winhttp, and possibly a core foundation implementation. You either need to abstract this and write an implementation for each platform, or use a library that does it for you. There are a few options. Boost has an http client you could use. Also, the AWS SDK for C++ has an http implementation that will do this for you.

Your other option is to read the HTTP spec, open the socket yourself and make the request manually. Fair warning however, this is non-trivial especially if TLS is involved.

If you want to write it yourself, I recommend libcurl for your linux implementation. You are more than welcome to use the examples here as a starting point. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-cpp/tree/master/aws-cpp-sdk-core/include/aws/core/http

Comment: Libcurl is available on many platforms, not just Linux: "*libcurl is **highly portable**, it builds and works identically on numerous platforms, including Solaris, NetBSD, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Darwin, HPUX, IRIX, AIX, Tru64, **Linux**, UnixWare, HURD, **Windows**, Amiga, OS/2, BeOs, Mac OS X, Ultrix, QNX, OpenVMS, RISC OS, Novell NetWare, DOS and more...*" The portable solution is to use libcurl on all of your target platform implementations.

Comment: @Remy It all depends on what kinds of dependencies are an option for you. If you can handle the build process for each platform (windows is the one thats painful for curl), then that is a fine solution. I find it simpler to implement windows using winhttp, libcurl for everything else. If you need ios support, then core foundation. Curl is already on osx. That way there are no dependencies you need to worry about.